# C# LINQ - Order List by an int and alternate result between other int "odd and even"

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to order a list of players for a turn based game and i have the following data structure:

```cs
public class PlayerTurn {
  public int energy;
  public int team; //Can be 0 or 1
}

public List<PlayerTurn> turnList = new List<PlayerTurn>();
```

Let's say that we have 4 players, 2 on each team like this:

| Player | Energy | Team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Player 1 | 10 | 0 |
| Player 2 | 30 | 0 |
| Player 3 | 5 | 1 |
| Player 4 | 60 | 1 |

How i can order this list in a way that the player with most energy will be first, but alternating between the teams while keeping the order by energy? The result expected is something like:

| Player | Energy | Team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Player 4 | 60 | 1 |
| Player 2 | 30 | 0 |
| Player 3 | 5 | 1 |
| Player 1 | 10 | 0 |

Is possible to achieve that only with Linq? Without using Linq is also acceptable.

EDIT:
Here's the link with a test of two approaches by @GianPaolo and @VadimMartynov
https://dotnetfiddle.net/0O22dX

Comment: So, you want to order by `Energy` in descending order and in *case of tie* altering `Team`?

Comment: yes, i want to order by energy descending. But always altering between team 0 and 1 and so on. (or 1 and 0)

The thing is that the first player must be with the highest energy

Comment: IMO, a LINQ query is going to be overly complex. Just create 2 collections, order each one by energy, and then alternate turns by selecting from either list. This will be much more readable and maintainable. K.I.S.S. FTW.

Comment: I'm with you @MetroSmurf, just posted an answer with that kind of implementation.
Maybe is doable with Linq only, but I doubt it can be easy (i.e. readable and maintainable). Linq is a great tool, but it's not always the  tool to pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go splitting the list in two, one for each team.
then sort both of them and then, very old style, pick one element at time from each list

```
List<PlayerTurn> allPlayers = new List<PlayerTurn>();// populated somehow

List<PlayerTurn> teamOne = allPlayer.Where (p=> p.Team = 1).OrderByDescending(p=>p.energy).ToList(); 
List<PlayerTurn> teamZero = allPlayer.Where (p=> p.Team = 0).OrderByDescending(p=>p.energy).ToList(); 

// which team go first?
var firstTeam = teamOne[0].energy >= teamZero[0].energy ? teamOne : teamZero;
var secondTeam = firstTeam == teamZero ? teamOne : teamZero;

var sorted = new List<PlayerTurn>();

// now zip the two teams
for (int i = 0; i < teamOne.Count(); i++) // TODO: check lists are same length
{
    sorted.Add(firstTeam [i]);
    sorted.Add(secondTeam [i]);
}

return sorted;
```

Comment: Maybe a use case for [Linq `Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2__)? Although it has the disadvantage it zips into a tuple by default.

Comment: I'd say no; Linq Zip is for "take something from each element in list1 and something from the corresponding element in list2, and create something wich is the _union_ of the starting elements" 
Here I used zip in the comment in the meaning "pick from 1, then from 2, then from 1 and so on". Can be misleading given the existing Linq Zip, I agree

Answer (score 2):

1. Order players by their energy with [`OrderByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending).
2. Group they by team with [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby). After that you will have 2 ordered groups for each team.
3. Tricky moment! Now you can merge this 2 lists in 1 structure with extra index property from each list. We use `teamIndex` as an index of team and `playerIndex` as a players index inside their team. We create a new objects for each player with 3 properties: player himself, team (group) index, player index. Here we use [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types) to create an object without type declaration.
4. Now order result by player index with [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby).
5. And then by team index with [`ThenBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby).
6. Select a player with [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select).

```
var result = turnList
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.energy)
    .GroupBy(p => p.team)
    .SelectMany((team, teamIndex) => team
        .Select((player, playerIndex) => new { player, teamIndex, playerIndex }))
    .OrderBy(item => item.playerIndex)
    .ThenBy(item => item.teamIndex)
    .Select(item => item.player)
    .ToList();
```

It's important to use `teamIndex` in the step 3 because team with the best player always be in `[0]`-th place in a grouped list because we ordered all players in the step 1 first.

Comment: Thank you for your time and the explanation Vadim, it was really helpful to get some understand of how LINQ works.

I'll accept the other user answer as the result was what i'm looking for (See the original post the link with the test code)

Comment: @DênisFernandes oh thanks for a great interactive example, I accidentally broke my code while trying to make it even more concise :)
Now I fix only 1 line from my example and it works as expected. It should be `.SelectMany((team, teamIndex) => team.Select((player, playerIndex) => new { player, teamIndex, playerIndex }))` instead of `.SelectMany((team) => team.Select((player, playerIndex) => new { player, team.Key, playerIndex }))`